# Mercurial/TortoiseHG - empty or missing revlog for Thumbs.db

Tags: mercurial, push, tortoisehg

I use **Tortoise 2.7.1** on a **Windows 8.1** machine

I'm trying to **push** my project to the common repository (**Windows Server 2003 R2**) and it's aborting with the following message:

> abort: empty or missing revlog for image/Thumbs.db

I must add that I recently disabled the creation of **Thumbs.db** and started to delete the existing ones.

After I got this error, I tried to add Thumbs.db to **.hgignore** and **commit + push**. As before, **commit** was good, but **push** still gave me the same message.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Setnara

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it in this way:

- remove the file ( image/Thumbs.db, in your case) from the disk
- in Hg, "forget" for the file ( image/Thumbs.db )
- in Hg, "commit"
- added the file ( image/Thumbs.db ) again in the directory
- in Hg, added the file
- in Hg, "commit"

Answer (score 0):

> started to delete the existing ones

It looks like you also deleted (probably recursively) some files in the Mercurial repositories and it is (or they are) now corrupted.. :-(

If you can find the repository on the disk, you can check its state with the following command: "`hg check`" (I do not know if Tortoise has such a command in the menus) and this will tell you if you have a corruption or not.

If this is the case, I'd suggest to make a backup of your files, remove the corrupted repository, and to clone it again from the central common repository, then checkout the files and compare them with the saved ones (you might have worked on some files and not committed them).

Hope it'll help.

Answer (score -1):

I have just had the same problem.

If you still have the files in the trash, there is a possibility that the files in question still exist. If this is the case, you can just restore the files and push.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question as the question states that the existence or pushing of the Thumbs.db isnt wanted.